# react-query - What's the difference between useQuery and useMutation hook?

Tags: react-query

Trying to find an answer regarding react-query.

What's the difference between useQuery and useMutation?

From what i understand useQuery's are dependent calls.

useMutation are for posts that require updating the current state (cache invalidation, etc)

is that the correct assumption?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From Tanner Linsley:

> The difference is the flow of data. `useQuery` is used to query async
> data, `useMutation` is used to mutate it. Or in the traditional CRUD
> speak:
>
> - Read: useQuery
> - Create/Update/Delete: useMutation

https://twitter.com/tannerlinsley/status/1324384797939003393

Comment: Generally yes, however you could still use useMutation to read data in some cases. Eg: Triggering a request on a user action.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting Tanner Linsley (the creator of react-query)

> useQuery is declarative, useMutation is imperative.
> Source: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#differences-to-usequery

Which means, useQuery runs when component is in focus, or is mounted; whereas useMutation has to be 'invoked'.

Also, as you may call same `useQuery` multiple times from multiple locations, that is not the case with `useMutation`.

Comment: Source : https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#differences-to-usequery